# How do I get this React form to render onto my page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

As a preface I'm very new to using React.js so I'm still very much learning the basics of how to use React. I am trying to get this React form to render on my webpage but for some reason it isn't rendering. This is quite literally the very first thing I've done on React so if I really messed up I apologize in advanced.

I've added extensions into my browser that will allow React to render along with doing some slight modifications to my code that got rid of all of the errors on the console within in the browser that I am using (Google Chrome), but yet the form is still not rendering.

```
    const React = require("react");
    const ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

    class LoginForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userName: "",
        password: ""
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
}

handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "text";
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
        // userName: event.target.userName,
        // password: event.target.password
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <form class="col s12" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input
                        name="userName"
                        id="username"
                        type="text"
                        class="validate"
                        value={this.state.userName}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        required="true"
                        aria-required="true" />
                    <label for="username">
                        Username
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input
                        name="password"
                        id="password"
                        type="password"
                        class="validate"
                        value={this.state.password}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        required="true"
                        aria-required="true" />
                    <label for="password">
                        Password
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <button id="loginBtn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit" formaction="/login">
                        Login
                    </button>
                    <button id="signupBtn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit" formaction="/signup">
                        SignUp
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
    }

    ReactDOM.render(LoginForm, document.getElementById("front_form"));
```

As stated before I'm not getting any more errors within the browser console, the only problem is that the form isn't rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Add brackets around the component in the render method

```
ReactDOM.render(<LoginForm />, document.getElementById("front_form"));
```

Also make sure that the front_form element exists.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You want to render an instance of `LoginForm`:

```
 ReactDOM.render(
  <LoginForm />, // <<<
  document.getElementById("front_form")
);
```

I'm surprised that this does not throw an error though.

Comment: I tried this as well but it didn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/anujladia/zv4893gt/

This is the working fiddle for the above problem. The form is getting rendered. 
There is 1 important change that will make the form get rendered.

```
ReactDOM.render(<LoginForm />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Since you have already tried this, I would ask you to check the id [front_form] also where you are trying to insert this form. Possibly, that can also be wrong.

Hope so this works.
If yes then continue.

Since you are new to react. I found other problems also which I would like to correct here.

1. In handleInputChange, value will be target.value
2. class will be className
3. for will be htmlFor
4. In react you don't need to add required="true", just adding required will be enough.

2, 3, 4 you would have been getting on console also.